# PIC18F4520 ADC Conversion in MC18

Tags: pic, adc, c, mplab, pickit

I have a dilemma.

I need to read ADC values from [PIC18F4520](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39631e.pdf). My configuration, and code, is as follows:

```
#define OSC INTIO67
int adc_result = 0;

void main(void)
{
    OSSCON = 0x70; //Set it as 8Mhz.
    OSCTUNEbits.PLLEN = 1; //Enable PLL 4x multiplier, thus we have 32 Mhz internal clock.

    //Set PORTA direction ports as input
    TRISA = 0xFF;

    OpenADC( ADC_FOSC_32      &
         ADC_RIGHT_JUST   &
         ADC_4_TAD,
         ADC_CH0          &
         ADC_REF_VDD_VSS  &
         ADC_INT_OFF, ADC_5ANA);

    while (1) {
        SetChanADC(ADC_CH0);
        ConvertADC();
        while (BusyADC());
        adc_result = ReadADC();
    }
    CloseADC();
}
```

The issue is this:

1. When I run it in MPLAB v8.x, my reading is slightly off, and terminates my debugging.
2. I can't debug the PIC again since I get errors like "Cannot enter debug mode."

How do I fix those issues? Also, is my ADC configuration correct (seeing that ADC requires a clock to do ADC conversion) with my internal clock? Is this correct to set the clock signal to 32 MHz.

I am programming using PicKit2 (with the black button).

Comment: Just to clarify: are you debugging a real device or are you simulating it? Are you including the right header for the device (no includes shown in your code)?

Comment: I'm debuggging a real device. I've only set `WDT` to `OFF` and `LVP` to `OFF`. My includes are `18f4520.h`, as well as `adc.h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting the clock signal of the ADC to 32MHz. The parameter `ADC_FOSC_32` divides the clock by 32 (see page 225 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39631E.pdf)). This ensures, together with the aquisition time select bits (`ADC_4_TAD` in your case), the minimum (/maximum) A/D aquisiton time (see page 359). When you hurt these requirements you will not get valid/accurate results.

With the equations given on page 228 you can do the math and verify, that the requirements are met.

Some other points:

- In your code you are never starting the ADC conversion by calling `ConvertADC`.
- You are configurating port `a` as output by setting `TRISA = 0x0;` but you want it to be configured as input (as your comment is saying). `TRISA = 0xFF;` would configure all pins on port a as input.

---

To expand a bit on the aquisiton time (\$T_{AD}\$): This time is needed for the internal circuitry to probably charge. When this time is too short, you will get no/bad results.

For 32Mhz (without divisor) \$T_{AD}\$ would be 31ns. That is too fast. At least 0.7us are required for the ADC to work probably. So you select a proper divisor to get \$T_{AD}\$ above 0.7us. A divisor of 32 will do it here, \$T_{AD} = 1\$us > 0.7us.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I set the clock signal of ADC to `Fosc` (in this case, 32Mhz)? Also, I do have `ConvertADC()`, it was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: Again: you have to verify that the aquisiton time (\$T_{AD}\$) is met. On page 359 you will see the minimum \$T_{AD}\$ is 0.7us. So for a higher oscillator frequency you have to select a bigger divisor. Table 19-1 will give you an overview. I would recommend you to **read the datasheet**, at least section 19, ADC.